# Does App Insights render application map using sampled data when sampling is enabled?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I have an App Insights which received telemetry data for multiple applications. I have enables sampling in order to reduce telemetry data ingestion.
Does AI uses sampled data to render application map?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. It builds up the map based on a set of queries of the ingested data as explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map?tabs=net#composite-application-map):

> The app map finds components by following HTTP dependency calls made between servers with the Application Insights SDK installed.
>
> This experience starts with progressive discovery of the components. When you first load the Application Map, **a set of queries is triggered to discover the components related to this component**.

Data that is not ingested cannot be queried. Normally that won't be an issue: in a given timeframe some dependency telemetry should still be ingested so it could still build a map, but metrics like performance, fail rates & call rates might be less accurate.